# iPhone - nil button outside the method?

Tags: iphone

I am creating a button like this inside a method:

```
UIButton * btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50);
[btn setTitle:@"Hello, world!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:btn];

myButton = btn; 
// I am saving the btn reference to this ivar declared on .h as UIButton.
```

At another point of the code I try to use myButton and it is always nil.

I have tried to retain btn after assigning it to myButton on the original method but myButton is always nil.

self.view is always there.
btn is never released.

Why myButton is nil?

I know I can create the button using alloc, but I am just trying to understand this.

thanks.

Comment: you're probably looking for self.myButton = btn;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIButton * btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

here you get an autorelease object of UIButton.

if want to access this button at other places so for this purpose,make it a property and use

```
UIButton * btn = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
```

or
creating by alloc and release it in dealloc .

**Edit**

in .h

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *myButton;
```

and in .m

```
self.myButton=btn;
```

and release it in dealloc.

Comment: ok, but Wouldn't it be retained due to the fact it was added as a subview to self.view?

Answer (score 0):

OK. You should try the below code

UIButton * btn = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];

myButton = btn;

It will surely work.

Answer (score 0):

At another point of the code, my guess is that you are using a different MyButton variable than the one you assigned from btn.  Perhaps an instance inside a different object, or a local covering the instance, etc.

The btn object should be retained by the addSubView call.  But if you remove this button from being a subview, it will be autoreleased.

Answer (score -1):

Because nowhere u have initialized the Button, that is why its giving u nil value.

Comment: The button is initialized `UIButton * btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];` creates a new button for you.